# Echo PHP variable inside jQuery SwitchCase?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery script that I am including on a PHP page that takes mt content and creates facebook/myspace share links.  I am having trouble echoing PHP code inside of the swith case statement that builds the share URL's.  Here's my code:

case 'facebook':
    this.href += '?t=' + document.title + '&u=http://foobar.com/detail.php?id=';
    break;

The server isn't parsing the PHP code correctly, it's passing the value `id=<?php echo "1";?>` rather than 1.  Can I not insert PHP code into a javascript include?

Comment: What file is your code located in? If your server isn't parsing the file as PHP, then it's not going to work.

Comment: The included file is a .js, but the parent file is .php

Comment: You must put your php code in a php file. have a look here http://codepad.org/B8Zy5Xti (look at the output part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1. In your file.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var varName = "<?php echo '1'; ?>"; // global
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Option 2. create a PHP file that returns the javascript content type [externalphp](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

By default, apache with mod_php doesn't parse files with a .js extension. That behaviour can be modified in the apache config files.

Alternatively (this solution will be less heavy on the parser because it wont parse *all* .js files), give the javascript files you need to parse a .php extension

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in a variable instead ?

```
var varName = '<?php echo "1"; ?>' ; or var varName = "<?php echo '1'; ?>";
```

and then use that variable in your javascript code.

You may need to use praseInt(...) to get a number through.